# Retrieve the newly added comments from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Giving a PostId i'm trying to retrieve all the comments attached to this post by using the **graphApi**. Its simple to retrieve the comments for the first time, i just keep following the ***next*** link in the ***paging*** propertie of the api response.

But to keep this list of comments up to date i need to retrieve the newly added comments. I tried using the cursor ***After*** (stored from the last  retrieved page) but it's not working as expected, using the parameter ***since*** in the query doesn't work either (seems that it is not supported by the endpoints */comments*).

Can please someone gives me an alternative solution?

Comment: What about use of 'since' isn't working? Are you using Webhooks to be notified when a new comment is returned, or polling?

Comment: "since" is not working for me with the comment endpoint i tried using both Unix timestamp and formated date ,but it's working fine with Posts retrieving . For the Webhooks, unfortunately i can't use it because i don't have the page token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said 'since' is not supported by the endpoint '/comments' because the api use cursors for the pagination (next, after and befor fields).

The use of the cursor 'after' will not work neither, because the its value is valide for a short period of time ([docs link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api))

[image: graph api docs]

So my solution was to use an ordred query to get the comments

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/[post-id]/comments/&filter=stream&order=reverse_chronological
```

, i save the `created_time`of the first comment as `last_update_time`. Then the next time i execute my code i check for each comment the time when it has been created if it's grater than the last update time i save it

```
while (comment.created_time > last_update_time):
    comments_list.add(comment)
    comment = comments.next()
if (len(comments_list)>0):
    last_update_time = comments_list[0].created_time
```